# Discretize a log normal distribution

Tags: python

My exercise is to discretize a log normal distribution. My plan is as follows: I first determine an evenly spaced vector in some positive interval. Let's say

```
np.linspace(5,20, 50)
```

then, calculate the probability of log normal distribution with some mean and variance at each element in the vector. This will give me a vector of probabilities. Then, I can normalize this probability vector by dividing each element by the sum of elements.

I am struggling to write down this in python. Can you give some help?

Comment: Have you taken some sort of shot at this?  If you've got something, show us.

Comment: @DEJABLUE Welcome to Stackoverflow! This i a good quetion but as a rule, you should try to explain what you have done so far to solve it on your own. Share some code of your own and I am sure people will be glad to help you.